# SQLServer JSON column data to a temporary table

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016. The column in question contains JSON. It always stores data in below format;

{"question1":"123","question2":"123","reference-id":"Z6SIPLGKE56"}

So, multiple rows will have same structure with different values.

Is there a way i can retrieve it back as a table? or put it into a temporary table? So final output will be like;

```
question1 | question2 | reference-id|....
123       |    123    | Z6SIPLGKE56
456       |    456    | Z6SWFLGKE56
```

The end result I am looking at is export the results to a CSV. I can do this outside of the SQL Server, but was wondering whether it's possible with built-in features of SQL Server(With current searches I did, seems like the available functions such as openjson etc.. doesn't allow you to do this in one pass).

**UPDATE 1 - Since more details are requested by commentros**

This is a survey application. So, users can design their own surveys. The structure is stored as json. As a start let's assume each survey has same set of questions. (ex:- Survey 1 has 5 questions where as Survey 2 has 10 questions)

Now, let's say two users fill the survey 1. Sample data if visualized in json is as follows:

**from user 1:**

{"forms-survey-client-reference-id":"RYRT4ZU1ZO","question1":"ans1","question2":"ans2"....}

**from user 2**

{"forms-survey-client-reference-id":"RYRT4ZU1FE","question1":"asdf","question2":"dfhdsf"....}

So the CSV output for this survey has to be: (ignore the column order)

```
question1 | question2 | reference-id|....
asdf      |    dfhdsf | RYRT4ZU1FE
ans1      |    ans2   | RYRT4ZU1ZO
```

Now consider survey 2 has the following structure after submitting data from:

**User 1**

{"forms-survey-client-reference-id":"RYRT4ZU1ZO","question1":"ans1","question2":"opt1,opt2,opt3"....}

**User 2**

{"forms-survey-client-reference-id":"RYRT4ABCZO","question1":"ans1","question2":"opt1,opt2"....}

Notice for question 2, users has selected multiple answers (checkboxes) and they are stored as a general string with comma separated(User 1 has selected 3 items and User 2 has selected 2 items)

The CSV output for above should be:

```
question1 | question2      | reference-id|....
ans1      | opt1,opt2      | RYRT4ZU1ZO
ans1      | opt1,opt2,opt3 | RYRT4ABCZO
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is your JSON structure you can use the following

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = '{"question1":"123","question2":"123","reference-id":"Z6SIPLGKE56"}'

    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT [key] JsonKey , value JsonValue 
    FROM OPENJSON (@json) 
    ) X
        PIVOT 
            (
            MAX(JsonValue) FOR JsonKey IN ([question1], [question2], [reference-id])
            ) P
```

If the structure is not going to be similar you'll need to create dynamic pivot

you can also do this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = '{"question1":"123","question2":"123","reference-id":"Z6SIPLGKE56"}'

    SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON (@json) 
        WITH ([question1] INT '$."question1"',
              [question2] INT '$."question2"',
              [reference-id] varchar(100) '$."reference-id"')
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is with `OPENJSON` and `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @JsonTable TABLE(json nvarchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO @JsonTable VALUES
      (N'{"question1":"123","question2":"123","reference-id":"Z6SIPLGKE56"}')
    , (N'{"question1":"456","question2":"456","reference-id":"Z6SIPLGKE57"}');

SELECT
       question1
     , question1
     , reference_id
FROM @JsonTable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json)
WITH (   
      question1 int '$.question1'  
    , question2 int '$.question2'  
    , reference_id varchar(20) '$."reference-id"'  
 );
```

Comment: Forgot to add something important. what you get as "question1/2" are all dynamic (meaning users are defining those questions. So basically the only thing static in this case is the delimiter (comma) and then the key/value pair. From the examples provided i see that this is not possible to do straight from SQL Server.

Comment: @user2058413, when you mentioned static in your question, I thought you meant static schema. Are you saying the number of questions in each JSON value might vary and have different question (property) names? Does every value have a `reference_id`? Add sample data and expected results to your question that shows the dynamic values. There might be a T-SQL solution, albeit ugly, or it might be better to do this in the app.